# android studio LinearLayout reverse Widgets/views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

LinearLayout reverse btn's the right one in Android studio become in the left on the device ( I use real device )

in Generally it is Horizontal problem the right is left and opposite

**On android studio design screen**

[image]

**On real device Galaxy S5**

[image]

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/button" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I also tried **GridLayout** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If it's matter :
I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
Android-studio Version : 2.1.2
The device: Samsung Galaxy S5 
Android system Version : 5.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are building an app in Arabic, Urdu, Hebrew, etc... or any language that is written from right to left you should set:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

to your `manifest.xml` at `<application>` tag.

Comment: This is very nice Sathish.